Minimum of the dot product over the vertices of a regular n-simplex
For $n \geq 2$, let $\Delta^n$ be a regular $n$-dimensional simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ centered at the origin $0$ and inscribed in the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Let $v_0,\dots,v_n \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ be the vertices of $\Delta^n$. I'm trying to compute :
$$ r_n = \inf_{e \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \max_{0 \leq j \leq n} |\langle e,v_j \rangle| $$
I also am pretty sure that $r_n$ is related to the radius of $\Delta^n \cap -\Delta^n$. Indeed
\begin{align*}
x \in \Delta^n \cap -\Delta^n 
&\iff x \in \bigcap_{j=0}^{n} \left\lbrace y \in \mathbb{R}^n : \langle y,v_j\rangle \geq -\frac{1}{n} \right\rbrace \cap \bigcap_{j=0}^{n} \left\lbrace y \in \mathbb{R}^n : \langle y,v_j\rangle \leq \frac{1}{n} \right\rbrace \\
&\iff x \in \bigcap_{j=0}^{n} \left\lbrace y \in \mathbb{R}^n : |\langle y,v_j\rangle |\leq\frac{1}{n} \right\rbrace \\
&\iff \max_{0 \leq j \leq n} |\langle y,v_j\rangle | \leq \frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}

Could you explain how you solved it for $n=2,3$ ? I don't get the same answer as you.

I would believe that the inf is attained when $\langle e,v_i\rangle=0$ for all $i$ except two (which are then forced to be opposed), this can probably proved by assuming that we have $e$ such that at least three of those are non zero, then there is one with smallest absolute value, we can set it to $0$ by increasing the rest while remainig on the unit sphere. Suppose WLOG that those are $v_1$ and $v_2$. Project them onto the plane with $0$ inner product with all $v_i$, $i\geq 3$, then I think that their norm is $\sin(2\pi/3)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$ which is then your answer.

I meant $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ for $n=2$. As for the case when $n=3$, I'm not certain about my calculation yet. I believe your calculation is correct (and I'm glad because it was the constant I needed for my theorem).

i edited my post with you remarks

This answer only covers the case of odd $n$. I do describe my guess of what happens when $n$ is even, but I already rushed it once, and don't have a proof :-(

I recycle the trick of embedding the space $\Bbb{R}^n$ isometrically into $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ in such a way that $\Bbb{R}^n$ becomes the orthogonal complement $V$ of
the all ones vector $\mathbf{1}=(1,1,\ldots,1)\in\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$. In other words,
$$
V=\{(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\Bbb{R}^{n+1}\mid \sum_{i=0}^nx_i=0\}.
$$
We can then choose the vertices of the simplex to be the $n+1$ points with a single coordinate $=n$, and the rest of them all $=-1$. In other words,
$$
v_j=(n+1)e_j-\mathbf{1}, j=0,1,\ldots,n
$$
where $e_i,i=0,1,\ldots,n$ are the basis vectors of $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$. Observe that subtracting the all ones vector makes $v_j\in V$.
So this regular $n$-simplex is inscribed in the sphere of radius $\sqrt{n^2+n}$ instead of $1$. Sorry about that, I just love integers as coordinates :-). Luckily we can easily rescale at the end.
A way to use the symmetry is to observe that any permutation of the coordinates is a an orthogonal linear transformation that preserves the inner products as well as the set of vertices of the simplex. There any permutation of the coordinates preserves the maximum as well as the minimum inner product. So without loss of generality we can assume the coordinates of the vector $e=(e_0,e_1,\ldots,e_n)$
are sorted, in other words
$$
e_0\ge e_1\ge \ldots\ge e_n.\qquad(*)
$$
As we have the constraint $e\in V$, the inner product of $e_0$ and $\mathbf{1}$ vanishes, and therefore $\langle e, v_j\rangle=(n+1)e_j$.
It follows immediately that the largest (positive) inner product is then with $v_0$
and the smallest (negative) inner product with $v_n$.
Minimizing $\max |\langle e, v_j\rangle|$ is therefore equivalent to minimizing
$\max\{|e_0|,|e_n|\}$ subject to the ordering constraint $(*)$ as well as the equations:

$\langle e,e\rangle=1$, and
$e\in V$, or $\sum_{i=0}^n e_i=0$.

A consequence (a known property of the regular simplex) of the fact $\langle e, v_j\rangle=(n+1)e_j$ is that
$$
(n+1)^2=(n+1)^2\langle e,e\rangle=\sum_{j=0}^n(\langle e, v_j\rangle)^2.
$$
It follows that ideally we would like to keep $(\langle e, v_j\rangle)^2$
independent of $j$, in other words, we prefer $|e_j|$ to vary as little as possible.
When $n+1$ is even, we can make all of the $|e_j|$ equal, so we assume next that $n$ is odd, so $n+1=2\ell$ is even. It is clear that in this case, the optimum solution is
$$
e_0=e_1=\cdots=e_{\ell-1}=-e_{\ell}=-e_{\ell+1}=\cdots=-e_n.
$$
There are $2\ell$ coordinates, and we split the squared norm equally among the coordinates to minimize the maximum absolute value. As $e$ is a unit vector, we
must choose $e_0=1/\sqrt{n+1}=-e_n$ and the rest accordingly.
With that $e$ we get $\sqrt{n+1}$ as the maximum absolute value of $\langle e, v_j\rangle$.
As the vertices of my simplex of choice had norm $\sqrt{n^2+n}$ this makes, after rescaling,
$$
\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n^2+n}}=\frac1{\sqrt n}
$$
to be the answer.

Moving to the case of an even $n=2\ell$. This time we cannot make all the $|e_j|$ equal, because the coordinates must add up to zero, and there are an odd number of them. I think that in this case the optimal choice of $e$
has the central coordinate $e_\ell=0$ and the rest as above, i.e.
$$
e_0=e_1=\cdots=e_{\ell-1}=-e_{\ell+1}=\cdots=-e_n.
$$
Alas, I cannot yet justify this. Anyway, we then have $|e_j|=1/\sqrt n$
whenever $j\neq \ell$, the maximum of $|\langle e, v_j\rangle|$ is equal to $(n+1)/\sqrt n$. After a similar rescaling the conjectural answer is thus that the minimal maximum of the absolute value of the inner product is $$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}n,$$
when $2\mid n$.

In the even case having the central coordinate $=0$ gives a lower maximum than any attempt to make positive (resp. negative) components have the same absolute value. Using the known answer in the case $n=2$ exposes the problem, and also suggests zero as the central coordinate.

Just an interpretation using the geometry on the sphere.

We have

$$\min_{e\in S} \max_{v \in V}|\langle e, v\rangle|= \min_{e\in S} \max_{v \in V\cup -V} \langle e, v\rangle$$

Since the dot product is $\cos$ of the angle, a decreasing function, we have the equivalent problem

$$\max_{e \in S} \min_{v \in W} \angle (e, v)$$
or, using the angular distance
$$\max_{e \in S} \min_{v \in W} d(e, v)$$
In other words, what is the smallest radius $r$, such that disks centered at points in $W$ cover the whole $S$. We can see this as a covering problem. Perhaps due to the regularity of $V$ there is a clear and easy solution here.
